# "A little" Vs. "The little" (in reply to "Have you got any money?")

Tags: difference, articles, adjectives, determiners

> A: Have you got any money?
>   B: Yes, **a** little
>   A: Have you got any money?
>   B: yes, **the** little

How **a little** is differ from **the little** in above context?

As far as I know the meaning of "a little" is "positive(some)," and meaning of "the little" is "not much" which can also be considered as **some**.

Comment: No, you say 'a little' i.e. a little amount of money in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“I have little money” vs. “I have a little money”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/i-have-little-money-vs-i-have-a-little-money)

Answer (score 2):

"A little"  is an indefinite but specific amount of money. It probably refers *specifically* to the amount of money the person has in his pocket, for example.

"The little" is rarely if ever going to be used in this context. *The* makes a definite reference and in this context one really needs to flesh out what definite money one is referring to, as in

1 the little that you gave me.

2 the little that is leftover from last night.

3 the little I have been saving for the past forty seven years.

Comment: Please review the guidelines on [editing posts](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/editing), and if you do not care for my changes, please make suitable ones yourself: the longstanding convention on this site is to use italics to distinguish use/mention, and your post will be easier to read if you place your listed examples in a proper list or in a blockquote.

Answer (score -1):

The correct form in your example is the first one:

> A: Have you got any money?
>   B: Yes, a little

B has a non-specific small amount of money, so we use the indefinite article (a).

You could alter the converstion to make "the" appropriate:

> A: Have you got any money?
>   B: Yes, but the little I have is for buying lunch

B has a small amount of money, but needs it to buy lunch. Here we are talking about a specific small amount of money (ie, the small amount that B has), so the definite article is used.

Comment: 'A little' is indefinite. But it is almost certainly 'specific', as in 'a little, which is in my pocket.' The indefinite article can refer to either specific or nonspecific items or referents. Consider: I need to buy a new car (nonspecific) and I just bought a new car (specific).

Comment: I would argue that in both cases you do not specify which new car you bought, therefore it is non-specific

Comment: I just looked up Quirk et al., Unit 5.26, "Specific and Generic Reference", and it seems to me that this use of **a** is not generic, so it must be specific. According to Quirk et al., **little** is a quantifier functioning as postdeterminer (Unit 5.23). In the unit's note [a] they mention the use of **little** with other determiners: "*that little money*". In 5.24 they say that **a** belongs not to the word **money**, but to the quantifier **little**, since we cannot say "yes, **a money**", but only "yes, **a little (money)**". (it's all linguistic lingo, of course, the "generic\specific"..)

Comment: If I say, I just bought a new car and it is sitting in the driveway, I am making an indefinite but specific reference. In sum, one may make either a specific or nonspecific reference with the indefinite article. And to avoid further quibbling, I suggest you consult a textbook on linguistics.

Comment: Either way your answer is more clearly written than mine, I defer to your knowledge and textbooks