# "A little is known ..." or "Little is known..."?

Tags: word-difference, quantifiers

**A little is known about the author of this book**.

I was asked to find the error in the sentence above. I thought there is no error in the sentence and told the same. But a few people are insisting that **a little** is incorrect. It should be replaced with **little** since it has negative connotation.

I couldn't understand how they can say it has negative connotation without further context.

I believe the sentence above is correct grammatically but has different meaning from the sentence with **little**.

Am I wrong? Did you find the sentence ungrammatical? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Related:[“not very much” vs. “a little”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107915/not-very-much-vs-a-little?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [“I have little money” vs. “I have a little money”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/i-have-little-money-vs-i-have-a-little-money?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [“A little” Vs. “The little”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72670/a-little-vs-the-little-in-reply-to-have-you-got-any-money?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Usually when someone prefaces a statement using "little" the meaning will be negative. I'm sure the instances of **Little is known about X** (we don't know not much) far outnumbers the **A little is known about X** (we know something)

Comment: @Mari-LouA So, do you mean the sentence is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I'd say the first sentence is unusual, and not idiomatic rather than ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples are technically grammatical:

> 1. **A little** is known about the author of this book.
> 2. **Little** is known about the author of this book.

However, the second sentence is much more idiomatic and likely to be said.  *Little is known about X* is a common way to phrase things, but the version with *a little* is not commonly said, so it's not really surprising that people would consider it a mistake.

People tend to expect things to fit the patterns they're used to hearing, and if you say something that *almost* fits a pattern they know, they're likely to think you made a mistake.  If they heard sentence 1, they'd probably think you meant to say sentence 2, even if both versions *are* technically grammatical.

---

Both *a little* and *little* are quantifiers which express small numbers.  So what's the difference?

- *A little* is a **positive paucal**<sup>1</sup> quantifier, indicating that a small amount does exist.  The emphasis is on the existence of a quantity, even if it's small.
- *Little* is an **approximate negative** quantifier, expressing that an amount is almost but usually not quite zero.  The emphasis is on the lack of existence, even though a very small amount may exist.

As a negator, *little* licenses negative polarity items:

> Very **little** is known at all about the author of this book.

This would be ungrammatical with *a little*, which is positive:

> ***A** very **little** is known at all about the author of this book.　←　*ungrammatical*

The same is true of *a few* (positive paucal quantifier) and *few* (approximate negative quantifier).

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> From Latin *paucus* 'few; little', indicating a relatively small number.

Comment: Suppose this sentence is given in an exam to find the error. Do I have to say the sentence is ungrammatical and the error is in _a little_ since most of the people expect that?

Comment: @Nagendra It depends on how the question is phrased.  In my opinion both sentences are clearly grammatical, so if they asked whether it was ungrammatical, I would say no.  However, if they asked you to pick the best improvement for the sentence, I would say replacing *A little is known about* with *Little is known about* is definitely an improvement.

Comment: They just asked me to find whether there is any error in the sentence. That's why I said no error. Thanks for clearing up my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Here we speak about **information** and it is uncountable so it's not 'a little information' but 'little information'.

Read it as:

- Little information is known about the author of this book. **Correct**
- A little information is known about the author of this book. **Incorrect**

> When we say **'a little'** or **'a few'** we mean a small amount,
>   but it's enough:

- John: Let's go out tonight.
- Lucy: Okay. I have a little money, enough for the cinema at least.

> On the other hand, **'little'** or **'few'** usually give us a
>   different impression. These also mean a small amount, but this time
>   the amount is almost nothing. If the noun is something that we want
>   (like money or friends) then using little or few means that we
>   dont have enough:

- John: Let's go out tonight.
- Lucy: Sorry, I have little money. I really can't afford to go out.

> Of course, if we use **'few'** or **'little'** with a noun that we don't want,
>   then it can have a positive meaning. It's good to have nearly no
>   problems, for example:

- There have been few problems with the new system, thankfully!
- Luckily, there is little crime in my town.
- I'm so pleased that I have few arguments with my family.
- It's great that there's been very little bad weather this month.

Source: http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/a-little-a-few.html

> We use little with uncountable nouns. We use few with plural countable
>   nouns. They are used in formal contexts:

- I’m not very happy about it but I suppose I have little choice.
- Few cities anywhere in Europe can match the cultural richness of
  Berlin.

**[talking about a period of history]**

- At that time few people traveled who didn’t have to.

Source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/little-a-little-few-a-few

Comment: Time is uncountable but "I always have **a little time** for a cup of tea at this hour of the day." A "How much money do you have?" B "**A little**"

Comment: I already checked the Cambridge dictionary. In the sentence _she drank some tea and ate a little bread_, **bread** is a mass noun and in the sentence _she saves a little money every month_, **money** is an uncountable noun. These sentences are from the same source. Check it once.